# Is it possible to configure DMARC to only receive reports for main domain and not sub domains?

Tags: dmarc

The question is pretty much in the title.

I have a domain, which has a subdomain with it's own DMARC record. The subdomain `marketing.xxx.com` is managed by a third-party and they handle the DMARC reports for their subdomain by themself.

I now want to analyze the regular corporate traffic on the main domain and am wondering, if it is possible to create a DMARC record for the main domain in a way, that the reports I receive don't contain traffic of the subdomain.

Is this possible with DMARC?

Comment: I think you should white-list sub-domains and then blacklist the main domain. If you don't have many sub-domains, it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: Yes, it's possible for this specific case.**

Just create a `DMARC` record in the organizational domain (`yourdomain.tld`).

**Background:**

If a subdomain is used in the header.from field, which has its own `DMARC` record published, the reports will (only) be sent to the email address registered in the `rua` tag.

If a subdomain is used without having a specific `DMARC` record published, the `DMARC` record for the organizational domain will be used.

**Examples:**

`Header.from`: `aaa@marketing.xxx.com` ---> `_dmarc.marketing.xxx.com` will be used.

`Header.from`: `aaa@bbb.marketing.xxx.com` ---> `_dmarc.xxx.com` will be used (assuming no `DMARC` record was published for `bbb.marketing.xxx.com`).

`Header.from`: `aaa@bbb.xxx.com` ---> `_dmarc.xxx.com` will be used (assuming no `DMARC` record was published for `bbb.xxx.com`).

For a Flow Diagram and a step-by-step description of the `DMARC` process, please see [section 4.3 of the DMARC RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-4.3). Point 7 outlines the behavior I described above.